# how to get the responding result of executing shell command in C?

Tags: c, linux, shell, ssh

Update: I tried to print the return value of `system()`. If ssh failed, it will return 65280, if it succeed ,it returns 0.

I want to ssh to another machine from my laptop,I write a C program, it access to that machine and touch a file on that machine. But sometimes the network is not stable or maybe that machine is down. Therefore, `ssh` will failed. How could I know the `ssh` failed in that program ? Sometime `ssh` to that machine succeed, but touch that file failed, how to distinguish them in the C program? How could I know that shell command failed is because of `ssh` failed not `touch` ? I don't want to stare at the screen, I want the program to check that automatically.

```
here is my code:
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>
int  main(int argc,const char *argv[])
{
while(1)
{
    system("ssh liulyix@localhost -p 22210 'touch script/rebooter.sh'");
    sleep(5);
}
}
```

Comment: You would need to open a socket and pass the request.  Then you can check which part is failing.  With your current code, nothing can be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the man page for system.

The proto type is

```
int system (constant char *command)
```

The return values are
-1 system was unable to execute the command because of say a fork failure. Look at the man page for execve and look at the error number which may raised. All these errnos are reasons why system will return -1.

All other returns ed values are the exit code of the command. 0 implies success, all other values imply the command crashed with EXIT_FAILURE.

Answer (score 1):

Using function `popen()` will be more easy:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>
int  main(int argc,const char *argv[])
{
   FILE *fp;
   fp = popen("ssh liulyix@localhost -p 22210 'touch script/rebooter.sh'", "r");
   while(1)
  {
    char *line; char buf[1024];
   line = fgets(buf, 1024, fp);
   if (line == NULL) break;
   printf("%s", line);

  }
  pclose(fp);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Actually, it not the result I want. I want to judge that whether it fails via ssh so that I can let that my laptop to send some notification to my website.  Do you have some methods like if that command failed, it will return a value so that I can know why it failed ?